# Able to generate UUID but was not able to insert the same into database

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate, guid, uuid

I tried generating GUID/UUID in MySQL using Hibernate. Below is the same code: Can anyone please suggest me where I am going wrong.

```
     public class MainClassLists {
        public static void main(String[] args){

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        ServiceRegistryBuilder registry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder();
        registry.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = registry.build();
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Users userNew = new Users();
                    userNew.setUserName("StyuytSra");
        userNew.setPassword("pyuass");
        userNew.setFirstName("sryuyaxcva");
        userNew.setLastName("sayuynxca");
        userNew.setBirthDate("2000-08-12");
        userNew.setGender("f");
        userNew.setEmailId("tesuyut@email.com");           
        userNew.setPhoneNumber(92672);
        userNew.setAccountNumber(8878);
        userNew.setAddress1("add1");
        userNew.setAddress2("add2");
        userNew.setCity("SD");
        userNew.setCountry("US");
        userNew.setZipcode(765);
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(userNew);
       Serializable uid= session.getIdentifier(userNew);

        System.out.println("User ID : "+userNew.getUserId()+""+uid);
               System.out.println();
        session.close();
        System.exit(0);
    } 
  }
```

Entity Class:

```
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "users", catalog = "test", schema = "")
 public class Users implements Serializable {
   @Id
@Column(name = "user_id")

@GeneratedValue(generator = "GUID")
@GenericGenerator(name = "GUID", strategy =  "com.List_Test.mainClass.InquisitiveUUIDGenerator")

private String userId;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "user_name", unique = true)
private String userName;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "password")
private String password;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;
@Column(name = "birth_date")
private String birthDate;
@Column(name = "gender")
private String gender;
@Column(name = "email_id", unique = true)
private String emailId;
@Column(name = "phone_number")
private Integer phoneNumber;
@Column(name = "account_number", unique = true)
private Integer accountNumber;
@Column(name = "address_1")
private String address1;
@Column(name = "address_2")
private String address2;
@Column(name = "city")
private String city;
@Column(name = "state")
private String state;
@Column(name = "zipcode")
private Integer zipcode;
@Column(name = "country")
private String country;
 public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getBirthDate() {
    return birthDate;
}

public void setBirthDate(String birthDate) {
    this.birthDate = birthDate;
}

public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

public String getEmailId() {
    return emailId;
}

public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
    this.emailId = emailId;
}

public Integer getPhoneNumber() {
    return phoneNumber;
}

public void setPhoneNumber(Integer phoneNumber) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}

public Integer getAccountNumber() {
    return accountNumber;
}

public void setAccountNumber(Integer accountNumber) {
    this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
}

public String getAddress1() {
    return address1;
}

public void setAddress1(String address1) {
    this.address1 = address1;
}

public String getAddress2() {
    return address2;
}

public void setAddress2(String address2) {
    this.address2 = address2;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public String getState() {
    return state;
}

public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
}

public Integer getZipcode() {
    return zipcode;
}

public void setZipcode(Integer zipcode) {
    this.zipcode = zipcode;
}

public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}
 }
```

Id generator class:

```
 public class InquisitiveUUIDGenerator extends UUIDGenerator {

private String entityName;

public void configure(Type type, Properties params, Dialect dialect) {
    entityName = params.getProperty(ENTITY_NAME);
    super.configure((org.hibernate.type.Type) type, params, dialect);
}

@Override
public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object object) {
    Serializable id = session
            .getEntityPersister(entityName, object)
            .getIdentifier(object, session);

    if (id == null) {
        return super.generate(session, object);
    } else {
        return id;
    }
}
}
```

Also, I tried inserting data with having a trigger before insert in MySQL database for the users table and tried mapping it to the entity class. I mapped it, but the @NaturalId(unique) key for which I give a key to the generator is not unique. Therefore there are duplicated mappings generated.
I am confused on what is the correct way to of generating GUID or UUIDs. Appreciate, if anyone can provide me an example. Below id DB script for the table

```
 CREATE TABLE `users` (
 `user_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
 `user_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `password` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
 `first_name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
`last_name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
 `birth_date` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `gender` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
`email_id` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`phone_number` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`account_number` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
`address_1` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`address_2` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`city` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
`state` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
`zipcode` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
`country` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `user_name` (`user_name`),
UNIQUE KEY `email_id` (`email_id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `phone_number` (`phone_number`),
 UNIQUE KEY `account_number` (`account_number`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The provided codes compile and run successfully. the id is generated but not inserted into the database table.
output would be something like this:
'User ID : ab9ffdb1-67ba-4d14-9038-3901d5032ab5ab9ffdb1-67ba-4d14-9038-3901d5032ab5'

Comment: Many of these string limits are really way too tight and seem totally random. 25 letters for a name is not adequate, as is 50 for an addressm but 100 for a birthdate seems way too huge. Use a `DATE` field for that. Most columns should be `VARCHAR(255)` as a default unless you have a really compelling reason. Likewise, using `int` for a postal code is going to be nothing but trouble: "10001-1010" is a valid US zip code. It's better to leave things open than to clamp down needlessly and truncate data.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. will make a default char length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having a separate class for generating UUID(as mentioned in my question) I used below annotations which I found in other stack overflow answers. I tried it earlier but wasn't working because I forgot to begin and end and commit the session transaction. though it was generating GUID it wasn't being saved to the database. I had to commit the transaction in order to get it saved. Below code should be annotated for the ID.

```
  @Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.GUIDGenerator")
@Column(name = "user_id", unique = true)
```